# How to show a userControl at the bottom of a page in wp silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone

I have a user control. I want to show it at the bottom of all page in my app.
I set the verticalOffset like this.

```
if (App.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor==150)
    popUp.VerticalOffset = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight - 230;// 160;
else
    popUp.VerticalOffset = App.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight - 160;
```

Where 160 is my userControl height.

I don't know the exact way. Anyway it's works for some device which have softkey.
Some device that satisfies if condition and has no softKey create a gap at the bottom of 70/72 pixels of the page.

Is it possible to check the softkey availability for silverlight or show the user control at the bottom exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only I need to add sizeChanged Events on page constructor
then set the verticaloffset of the popUp like this.

```
Popup popUP = new Popup();
public MainPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged;
 }

double systemTrayHeight =30;
double popUPHeight = 200;
private void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (popUP.IsOpen)
         popUP.IsOpen = false;
     popUP.Child = new PopUP();
     popUP.VerticalOffset = e.NewSize.Height + systemTrayHeight - popUPHeight;
     popUP.IsOpen = true;
}
```

[sample project](https://github.com/rezacse/PopUpAtPageBottom)